# Empty webpage displayed in IE11 after clicking submit button in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

IE11 displays nothing on webpage when I run my test case but works fine with Chrome and Firefox where it displays homepage. Doesn't work manually also.

Could you please help me what might have gone wrong?

- I checked all options in IE11 internet options.
- I tried InternetOptions -> Advanced -> checked&unchecked Accelerated graphics option but did not make any difference.

Comment: You could use the F12 tools to debug your webpage in IE11. See if there's any error in console. Can you please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the steps to reproduce so that we can test it in our side?

Comment: "Doesn't work manually also." Start there...

Comment: @orde You nailed it ^^^ big time :|